# StreamBridge: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "result" is null when handling XML message while upgrading to Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

While upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.3, the following exception starts to come up in a `@SpringBootTest` when a `StreamBridge` is about to send a message with contentType application/xml:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "result" is null
at org.springframework.cloud.function.cloudevent.CloudEventsFunctionInvocationHelper.doPostProcessResult(CloudEventsFunctionInvocationHelper.java:138)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.cloudevent.CloudEventsFunctionInvocationHelper.postProcessResult(CloudEventsFunctionInvocationHelper.java:114)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.cloudevent.CloudEventsFunctionInvocationHelper.postProcessResult(CloudEventsFunctionInvocationHelper.java:48)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:181)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:144)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:140)
at com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests.shouldSendMessage(DemoApplicationTests.java:33)
...
```

At first I thought it might be related to inconsistent use of dependency versions throughout the application, however the problem remained when I created a fresh spring application at start.spring.io using the following configuration:

build.gradle (simplified):

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.3'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

ext {
  set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.1")
}


dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-binder'
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        demo-out-0:
          destination: some.topic
          contentType: application/xml   <<<------ The test passes when I remove this line

      rabbit:
        bindings:
          demo-out-0:
            producer:
              routingKeyExpression: '''some.routing.key'''
```

DemoApplicationTest.java

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination outputDestination;

    @Test
    void shouldSendMessage() {

        var minimalXml = """
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
                <Config></Config>
                """;

        streamBridge.send("demo-out-0", MessageBuilder.withPayload(minimalXml).build());

        var actual = outputDestination.receive(1000, "some.topic");

        Assertions.assertThat(new String(actual.getPayload()))
                .isEqualTo(minimalXml);
    }
}
```

The above setup worked before migrating to Spring Boot 3. Note that I have replaced valid XML with a minimal example of XML.

The test fails with message `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "result" is null`. The test passes however when I remove the content type `application/xml` from the stream binding definition in the application.yml.

Would anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 6):

It might be helpful, I had a similar issue moving from Java 11 to Java 17 and up-scaling Kafka. I am using Avro but it might still be relevant for you.
I was receiving the same exception in my integration tests and after some debugging I realised that I needed to update the producer serializer configuration of the StreamBuilder binding.
Initially I had:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processToKafka-out-dlq.destination=myTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processToKafka-out-dlq.contentType=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.processToKafka-out-dlq.producer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

but after the migration I had to set:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processToKafka-out-dlq.destination=myTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processToKafka-out-dlq.contentType=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processToKafka-out-dlq.producer.use-native-encoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.processToKafka-out-dlq.producer.configuration.value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

No changes regarding StreamBuilder usage:

```
streamBridge.send("processToKafka-out-dlq", message);
```

Comment: For a fyi, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties for `useNativeDecoding`